# Add column based on search term

Tags: text-processing

I have a file a:

```
aaa  bbb  ccc  DDD  
ads  zzz  caa  DDD  
aba  bab  cac  DAD  
aad  cca  cas  SFD
```

and a file b:

```
DDD  5  
DAD  13  
SFD  11
```

I want to add a fifth column to file a based on file b, meaning search the term of column4 of file a in file b and add a fifth column to file a containing the respective value of column2 in file b.

Can you help me?

Comment: Ah ja, file a also has headers. So I would like to add the fith column also with a header (e.g. 'value').

Comment: What is the language you need? In bash it looks some weird. Python, perl or R fit besser.

Comment: Are strings in 1st column in file b unique? How many lines it has?

Comment: In principle the language does not matter, R I know a bit, so this is easiest.

Comment: yes, the strings in col 1 in file b are unique

Answer (score 2):

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2 -1 4 -2 1 <(sed '1d' file1 | sort -k4) <(sed '1d' file2 | sort)
```

`sed '1d'` is used to strip the header (1 line from the top)

then we join the first file on field 4 with the second file on field 1

also the files must be sorted for join to work properly so we sort file1 on the field it is joined on

the `-o` is the order in which to print the output N.M (where N=file and M=field)